# What is "Symmetry of Infinity" in electricity and magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge

I have this problem from my E&M textbook:

Two infinitely long wires running parallel to the x axis carry uniform charge densities $+\lambda$ and $-\lambda$ (see photo). Find the potential at any point $(x,y,z)$, using the origin as your reference.

[image]

The [solution](https://kmcatee.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/equipotential-surfaces/) to this uses a random point and solves the problem there:

[image]

It's stated that "due to the symmetry of infinity, we need only consider the z-y-plane. We plot an arbitrarily located point, without symmetry."

Once here I could do the math of this just fine, but I don't understand what "due to the symmetry of infinity" means. I tried to look it up online (including stack exchange) and all I could find were journals that were related to this. I could not access them, and even if I could I probably wouldn't understand what was going on anyway.

What is "the symmetry of infinity?" And how is it related to this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is not a technical term which you don't know, but merely a hand-wavey and brief way of pointing out that the charge distribution is independent of x and so the potential must also be independent of x.  "Infinity" is evocative of this fact because if the wires were not infinite in length, then the charge distribution (and the potential) would be dependent on x.

Comment: Yeah, the better way to put it would be "due to the translational symmetry of the infinite line charges, we only need to consider the $yz$-plane."

Answer (score 3):

I essence this is a two dimensional problem in a yz-plane because you cannot reference an absolute x-position relative to a featureless (infinite) line of charge.
The electric field looks the same at every possible value of x and this is possibly where the term “symmetry of infinity” comes from.
[physicspages.com](http://physicspages.com) is a good source of text book solutions including for this problem where the [x-independence is explained](http://physicspages.com/pdf/Griffiths%20EM/Griffiths%20Problems%2002.47.pdf) in a different way.